# Why is this String not matching this regex?

Tags: java, regex, string

I've got the following code:

```
public class testMatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dummyMessage = "asdfasdfsadfsadfasdf 3 sdfasdfasdfasdf";
        String expression = "3";
        if (dummyMessage.matches(expression)){
            System.out.println("MATCH!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH!");
        }

    }
}
```

I'd expect this to be a successful match as the dummyMessage contains the expression 3 but when I run this snippet the code prints NO MATCH!

I don't get what I'm doing wrong.

**OKAY STOP ANSWERING! .*3.* works**
This is an over simplification of an issue I have in some live code, the regex is configurable, and up until now matching the entire string has been okay, I've now had to match a part of the string and was wondering why it wasn't working.

Comment: Use a simple `dummyMesasge.indexOf("3") != -1` instead of the regexp.

Comment: +1 For "OKAY STOP ANSWERING!" :)) Many times I think the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It matches against the whole string, i.e. like `^3$` in most other regex implementations. So `3` does not match e.g. `333` or your string. But `.*3.*` would do the job.

However, if you just want to test if "3" is contained in your string you don't need a regex at all. Use `dummyMessage.contains(expression)` instead.

Comment: I bet it shoud be `.*?3.*`

Comment: True. Doesn't really matter though, it would only be relevant when using groups.

Answer (score 3):

[String#matches(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) Tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression.
your string dummyMessage  doesn't match expression, as it tries to check if dummyMessage  is 3  you probably want [String.contains(charseq)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead.

```
 String dummyMessage = "asdfasdfsadfsadfasdf 3 sdfasdfasdfasdf";
            String expression = "3";
            if (dummyMessage.contains(expression)){
                System.out.println("MATCH!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("NO MATCH!");
            }
```

Comment: It needs to be a regex, I need to see if it matches for now but later will need to extend it for regex matches. .*3.* works.

Comment: @OmarKooheji that regex would work for this special case .. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should match the whole string for `matches` to return true. Maybe try using `.*3.*`.

Answer (score 2):

It will match for such regex: `.*3.*`

Answer (score 2):

Use  contains(expression)

```
 String dummyMessage = "asdfasdfsadfsadfasdf 3 sdfasdfasdfasdf";
        String expression = "3";
        if (dummyMessage.contains(expression)) {
            System.out.println("MATCH!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH!");
        }
```

Comment: It needs to be a regex match, contains is not sufficient for my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

By default `String#matches()` test if string matches regular expression completely. To make it working replace

```
expression = "3"
```

with

```
expression = ".*3.*"
```

To match substring in string use `Matcher#find()` method.

Answer (score 1):

your regexp should rather be `.*3.*`

Answer (score 1):

the matches() method on String class check if the whole string matches.
I modified your code to:

```
public class testMatch
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String dummyMessage = "asdfasdfsadfsadfasdf 3 sdfasdfasdfasdf";
        String expression = ".*3.*";
        if (dummyMessage.matches(expression))
        {
            System.out.println("MATCH!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NO MATCH!");
        }

    }
}
```

and it now works

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for `matcher.find`:

```
String message = "asdfasdfsadfsadfasdf 3 sdfasdf3asdfasdf";
String expression = "3";

// Really only need to do this once.
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
// Do this once for each message.
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(message);
if (matcher.find()) {
  do { 
    System.out.println("MATCH! At " + matcher.start() + "-" + matcher.end());
  } while ( matcher.find() );
} else {
  System.out.println("NO MATCH!");
}
```

Comment: In retrospect yes this would probably have worked better. I'll update the next version of my code to use this rather than String.match

Answer (score 0):

Change the original regex accordingly - it is currently incorrect and does not match:

```
String expression = "(.*)3(.*)";
```

Or just use String.contains() - I'd say that is a lot more appropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Either you do it that way:

```
String dummyMessage = "asdfasdfsadfsadfasdf 3 sdfasdfasdfasdf";
String expression = "3";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*3.*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(dummyMessage);
boolean b = m.matches();
if (b) {
    System.out.println("MATCH!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH!");
}
```

Or this way:

```
String dummyMessage = "asdfasdfsadfadfasdf 3 sdfasdfasdfasdf";
String expression = "3"
if (dummyMessage.contains(expression)) {
    System.out.println("MATCH!");
}
else {
    System.out.println("NO MATCH!");
}
```